# Get Transactions from payment ID

Tags: monero-wallet-cli, monero-wallet-gui, monerod, mymonero, monero-research-lab

I know how to generate payment id and how payment id works. But how can i get all transactions for a payment id from monero wallet CLI. Is there a way to do that? And command for that will be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `payments` command in *monero-wallet-cli* lists the transactions matching specific payment ids.

```
payments payment_id_1 [payment_id_2 payment_id_3 ...]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer so basically for multiple payment id i need to use a array syntax "[....]" right?

Comment: No you don't need an array syntax, just put all the ids separated by spaces: ```payments 1212121212121212 3434343434343434 abcd987565456879```